# Angular $http calls not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple Angular $http.get and post calls. It works perfectly in IE but not in Chrome or Firefox.

I kept a break point in the JS and debugged, it just breaks exactly in the line of $http.get('urlAPI') and don't see any guidance for this. The debug takes me to the details of angular methods which I was not able to follow..

Anyone have faced a similar issue or any guidance here. I am using Angular version 1.5.8.

Here is my simple Angular code

```
$scope.wakeup = function() {
    $http.get('getTimings').then(function() {
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: Are you using any other libraries with angularjs ? try to comment all of them and create a simple `$http.get` request to see if it's working alone or not.

Comment: what's your api ?? is it .NET web API ?

Comment: Have you added an `onerror` to catch exception?

Comment: @Maximus It doesnt throw any error on the screen or on the console

Comment: @Dabbas This is on spring boot, so I am including all my angularJS links in my index.html along with JQuery

Comment: @DanielShillcock Sorry, where should I add this ?

Comment: Can you update your question with code that you are using?

Comment: @CrazyMac, so what you're saying is that the callback in `then` is not called? Add second error handler as well. Can you see the request executed in Network tab of devtools?

Comment: @DanielShillcock Added the code snippet

Comment: @Maximus When I debug, it goes to the line we have then but dont show any error and then goes to the end of method and redirects

Comment: I have updated @Cruzer's answer with an onerror

Comment: @DanielShillcock Sorry, I dont see the code for onerror

Comment: You won't see it until @Cruzer accepts my changes. I don't think it is worth registering my own answer for quite a small change.

Comment: @DanielShillcock I tried the onerror and here is the response I received
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: headersGetter/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" } and redirects to my default blank page

Comment: Any inputs from anyone?

Comment: It works in the Firefox debug mode but not without that in Firefox. Any guidance?

Comment: What I found is before any API call from angular to Spring, by default an API is called by Spring dispatcher and not sure where it is configured. My app routing is controlled by AngularJS and not sure how this goes to the default /login reference and takes me to a blank page

In IE, the blank JSON returned by /login is returned as a file but in Chrome and Firefox this is returning to a blank page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Use this following: 
If your server side scripting is PHP then it will work: (if ASP.NET you should add web service to GET in web.config file)

IMP: Please make sure you have used ng-app and ng-controller name exactly as used in html

```
 <p>Today's welcome message is:</p>

 <h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>

 <p>The $http service requests a page on the server, and the response is set as the value of the "myWelcome" variable.</p>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $http.get("welcome.php") // you can use welcome.htm also
 .then(function(response) {
 $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error)
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: This is on Java. I have the correct ng-app name and I have done many apps in the past but this is strange and it works in IE as well.

If these values are not correct, it should not work in IE as well

Comment: Thanks. It helped me partially to find my answer or at least guided me to get the answer. In IE, it was generating an empty json whereas in Chrome and Firefox it was taking me to the empty page. So all 3 had issues but my real issue was in the service API method.

Comment: Pls accept the answer then, It would helpful to other also.